# How would AML techniques work in Ripple?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, aml

Can anyone explain how AML rules, alerting, and FinCEN reporting would work under Ripple?

Comment: I would suppose it would only apply to gateways, and then it would be pretty clear?

Comment: @Murch I thought Ripple has a transitive property that masks the original transmitter and receiver (the "ripple"). In that case I would think it would complicate AML work, no?

Comment: mh, attempting an answer.

Comment: this article touches on Ripple and KYC: [CoinDesk - Ripple Labs’ Grand Plan to Build a Global Payment Protocol](http://www.coindesk.com/ripple-labs-grand-plan-build-global-payment-protocol/)

Answer (score 1):

AML is only applied to customer relationships. In this case that would be people that have an account with a gateway and are using said account to either deposit or withdraw massive amounts of money/crypto from the gateway.

It cannot apply to rippled balances, as you don't need to provide any information to another entity in Ripple in order to extend a trust line to said entity. I.e. there is no customer relationship in that case.

All of the above is AFAIK and IANAL.